# Jenkins slave override environment variable set by master when execute multibranch pipeline job

Tags: jenkins, master-slave, multibranch-pipeline

I have setup Jenkins with a `master` node running Ubuntu and a `slave` node. Currently Jenkins use to build Android app (`master` and `slave` have different `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` environment variables).

For `slave` I have configured environment variables as below:

[image]

The `free style` project run OK and the slave able to pickup the environment variable. A problem happens when I run multibranch pipeline job. It seems the job cannot pickup the `environment variable` always show error:

`SDK location not found. Define location with an ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variable or by setting the sdk.dir path in your project's local properties file at`

What is the root cause and how to make multibranch pipeline able to pick up correct environment variable?

Updated: I detect the problem because `slave` cannot override environment variable value set by `master`. But I don't know how to make slave able to override environment variable set by master.

Comment: Are you 100% sure your pipeline is correctly targeting your slave (and not running from the master) ?

Comment: Yes I can see from the console output that job is running from slave (have set master executor to 0). Freestyle Job run ok

Comment: actually my problem is slave cannot overide environment set by master `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT`